# Invalid menu directory 'Accessories/pcmanfm.desktop

Tags: python, system, raspberry-pi3, pi

Previously I installed the pytesseract lib on my Raspberry Pi, now I need more space, so I want to uninstall this lib. 
I used these command to uninstall the lib:

```
sudo apt-get remove tesseract-ocr
sudo apt-get remove <lib>
```

with `<lib>` being each of these libs:

- libc6
- libcairo2
- libfontconfig1
- libgcc1
- libglib2.0-0
- libicu55
- liblept5
- libpango-1.0-0
- libpangocairo-1.0-0
- libpangoft2-1.0-0
- libstdc++6
- libtesseract3
- tesseract-ocr-eng
- tesseract-ocr-osd
- tesseract-ocr-equ

but I have a big problem:
when I need to open the gile manager or lxtermenial, or any acsseories, I get this error:

```
invalid menu directory 'Accessories/pcmanfm.desktop'
```

Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi bat, welcome to SO! Please read up on [writing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on that part of the taskbar.  Select "Application Launch Bar Settings".  Reconfigure the buttons by deleting what's there and adding them again.